# Перевести день недели с английского на русский из MySQL в html

Tags: php, html, mysql

Нужно что бы дни недели выводились на русском, а не на английском.
Я так понимаю, что нужно что то сделать с локализацией, что все правильно работало.
В MySQL дата в формате (DATE)

```
<td style="border: 1px solid #172028;"><?php echo date('l',strtotime($row["date"])); ?></td>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `$days = ['Friday' => "Пятница"]`

Comment: И получай в запросе не наименование, а номер дня недели. Так будет проще на PHP транслировать...

Comment: Либо `IntlDateFormatter`